# Borel sigma algebra in topology and R

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a very basic question about which I am concerned. What is the difference between the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for a topological space and for $\mathbb R$? or they are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general topological space $S$ it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $S$. The same definition applies to $R$.

In the case of $R$ the Borel sets can be shown to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the intervals $(-\infty,x]$. This can be proved using the fact that every open set in $R$ is a countable union of open intervals.

Comment: wah it's very quick answer. thank you so much sir :)

Comment: hai, sir. can I find a red-line between Borel $\sigma$-algebra on topological space and Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$?